# How to achieve depth value invariance between two passes?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have two geometry passes. In the first pass, I write the fragment's depth value to a float texture with `glBlendEquation(GL_MIN)`, similar to dual depth peeling. In the second pass I use it for early depth testing in the fragment shader.

However, for some fragments the depth test fails unless I slightly offset the min depth value (`eps` below):

[image]

Setting up the texture:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, offscreenDepthMapTextureId);
glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RG32F, screenWidth, screenHeight);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, offscreenDepthMapFboId);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D,
  offscreenDepthMapTextureId, 0);
```

Note that the texture is used as a color attachment, not the depth attachment. I have disabled `GL_DEPTH_TEST` in both passes, since I can't use it in the final pass.

Vertex shader, used in both passes:

```
#version 430

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;

uniform mat4 mvp;
invariant gl_Position;

void main()
{
  gl_Position = mvp * position;
}
```

First pass fragment shader, with `offscreenDepthMapFboId` bound, so it writes the depth as color to the texture. Blending makes sure that only the min value ends up in the red component.

```
#version 430

out vec4 outputColor;

void main()
{
  outputColor.rg = vec2(gl_FragCoord.z, -gl_FragCoord.z);
}
```

Second pass, writing to the default framebuffer. The texture is used as `depthTex`.

```
#version 430

out vec4 outputColor;

uniform sampler2D depthTex;

void main()
{
  vec2 zwMinMax = texelFetch(depthTex, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), 0).rg;
  float zwMin = zwMinMax.r;
  float zwMax = -zwMinMax.g;
  float eps = 0;// doesn't work
  //float eps = 0.0000001; // works
  if (gl_FragCoord.z > zwMin + eps)
    discard;
  outputColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

The invariant qualifier in the vertex shader didn't help. Using `eps = 0.0000001` seems like a crude workaround as I can't be sure that this particular value will always work. How do I get the two shaders to produce the exact same `gl_FragCoord.z`? Or is the depth texture the problem? Wrong format? Are there any conversions happening that I'm not aware of?

Comment: You might also try to insert some `precise` qualifiers (shouldn't be neccessary, but worth a try).

Comment: @ChristianRau I tried `invariant precise vec4 gl_Position;`, but it didn't help. Both qualifiers actually have no effect at all.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried glDepthFunc(GL_EQUAL) instead of your in-shader-comparison-approach?
Are you reading and writing to the same depth-texture in the same pass?

Im not sure if gl_FragCoord's format and precision is correlated with the one of the depth-buffer. Also it might be a driver glitch, but glDepthFunc(GL_EQUAL) should work as expected.

Comment: In my fragment shader I need both the min and the max depth value, which is why I disabled depth testing, and use min blending instead. It's actually disabled in both passes. Depth testing with GL_LESS in the first pass would mean that I'd have to do another pass with GL_GREATER before the final pass, which I'd like to avoid. In the first pass I only write to `offscreenDepthMapTextureId`, in the second pass I only read from it.

Comment: I actually can't use `GL_DEPTH_TEST` in the final pass because the shader needs to a) modify the depth value and b) use early depth testing. Since it modifies it, hardware early depth testing wouldn't work.

Comment: Looks like a driver glitch then. Maybe gl_FragCoord.z is calculated just a bit different than the actual depth in the depth buffer, which would add rounding errors. Just a guess. Have you tested your program on different hardware? Especially on AMD and NVIDIA?

Comment: *"Looks like a driver glitch then. Maybe gl_FragCoord.z is calculated just a bit different than the actual depth in the depth buffer"* - Wouldn't have anything to do with it, since he doesn't use the depth buffer at all. He just uses `gl_FragCoord` in each pass.

Comment: You are right. My bad. Dear author: what is the precision of your (Context-provided) depth-buffer? I could imagine that the driver converts gl_FragCoord.z into that format before you can access it in the pixel-shader, but that would be bad behaviour.

Comment: It's `GL_RG32F` (see the `glTexStorage2D` call above).

Comment: I meant the context-provided depth buffer of your window.

Comment: @Marius Ah, so you mean the driver would always store `gl_FragCoord.z` in the precision of the currently specified depth buffer? Doesn't seem very likely, since the OP doesn't use a depth buffer at all (and using the default framebuffer's depth buffer precision as reference while rendering into a custom FBO would be completely stupid from the driver).

Comment: Yes it would be stupid, but such a glitch is the only reason for the precision issues I can think of right now. Just stick to your workaround if it works for you. Actually the workaround works even in case other drivers do not have these precision issues, so it's not that bad. Assuming incorrect behaviour for all setups would be.

Comment: Sorry Marius, I misunderstood. I just checked, the depth precision is 24 bits. I tried hacking freeglut to set it to 32, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use gl_FragCoord.z as the depth value.

In vertex shader:

```
out float depth;

void main()
{
   ...
   depth = ((gl_DepthRange.diff * (gl_Position.z / glPosition.w)) + 
             gl_DepthRange.near + gl_DepthRange.far) / 2.0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately I get very similar results. It gets (a lot) better if I use `noperspective`, but there's still artifacts. I also tried `precise` and `invariant`, didn't help either. I still have to add some small `eps` value to make it work.